# Oracle OLE DB Provider not Listed in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl, odac

I'm having an issue with SSIS and VS2015 CM.

I have a package that needs to connect with Oracle to get some data. I installed the ODAC for Win64 and the Oracle client but I can't see the Oracle provider for OLE DB listed in the providers list.

Although I can see the Microsoft OLE DB provider for Oracle it doesn't work when I try to use that provider either.

[image]

What should I do to get the Oracle OLE DB provider listed?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting when you try to use 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle'?

Comment: The error I get is: The specified provider is not supported. Please choose different provider in connection manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download and install the Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 32-bit:

**Download Link**

- [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) and NuGet Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)

**Helpful Links**

- [Oracle Provider for OLE DB Releasse notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/relnotes-088272.html)
- [Oracle Provider for OLE DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-089115.html)

Comment: I installed it and it didn't worked. Anything else I can try?

Comment: @MagdielAybar http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Only this install worked for me (for Visual Studio 2017):
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-utilsoft-downloads.html

Other ways to install OLEDB provider from multiple forums didn't work.