# SSIS AdoNet ODP Managed connection Issue where Tables are not showing up in the drop down

Tags: oracle, ssis, ado.net, sql-server-data-tools, odp.net

When I click the drop down in the source editor after entering a valid connection (and successfully testing said connection), I get the following error message:

> Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'xxxx'.
>   Could not create a DbProviderFactory class for the provider invariant name 'Sybase.Data.AseClient'. Verify that this provider is installed correctly on this computer.

As this is supposed to be an `ODP Managed Data provider`, i'm not sure why it is looking for a Sybase provider. As you can see here it appears as though it is using the correct DLL:

[image]

I have tried clearing both dll's out of the gac and then reinstalling the managed ODP, but I still get the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I searched over this issue for a while without finding any helpful articles or references.

If you are trying to connect to Oracle, then it is recommended to use [Oracle Attunity Connectors](https://www.attunity.com/content/microsoft-connectors-attunity/) which have been selected by Microsoft to be included with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

Also you can use [Oracle Provider for OLEDB](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html) which is the official provider made by oracle.

For more information, you can refer my answer on the link below where i provided information about the way to connect to oracle in SSIS and posted many helpful links:

- [Oracle provider for Oledb missing in VS 2015 Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320725/oracle-provider-for-oledb-missing-in-vs-2015-shell/54337473#54337473)

Comment: Thank you, however unfortunately it HAS to be this driver. I'll give you an upvote though.

Comment: @JacobAlley Are you working with oracle client 64-bit?

Comment: @JacobAlley check this link it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750902/oracle-connections-broken-in-ssis-after-uninstalling-32bit-version-of-oracle-cli/54754295#54754295